# Excel VBA code for categories the data

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file that contains some data in column B, now i wish to categories the data in A column like serial number first 1 to 5 again starts from 1 to 5 until the data ends,

for example in below format

```
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   D
5   E
1   F
2   G
3   H
4   I
5   J
1   K
2   L
3   M
4   N
5   O
```

I do not have existing code for above task please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the following

1. put 1 in the Cell A1
2. put  `=IF(OFFSET(A2,-1,0)=5,0,OFFSET(A2,-1,0))+1` in cell A2
3. double click in the bottom corner of cell A2, this will repeat the function for all cells in column A

hope that it will help you

Comment: Nice, is there a way to make it show "" when at the end of column B?

Answer (score 1):

Use some code

```
Sub DoItGood()
    Dim rws As Long, rng As Range, t As Range

    Columns(1).ClearContents

    rws = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Range("A1:A" & rws)

    x = 1
    For Each t In Range("A1:A5")
        t = t + x
        x = x + 1
    Next t

    Range("A1:A5").AutoFill Destination:=rng, Type:=xlFillCopy

End Sub
```

Comment: Bonus for being the only one to read the title and tech tags of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a repeated list of numbers from 1 to n downwards in rows with the following approach:

```
=MOD((ROW(A1)-1),n)+1
```

Take the integer remainder of the division row number (starting with 0) and `n`. You will get 0,1,2,...,n-1,0,1,2,...,n-1,0,1... To this add 1.

In your case n is 5:

```
=MOD((ROW(A1)-1),5)+1
```

filled downwards.

Comment: i found an answer for this doubt from  www.myworkbook.in

Comment: What doubts do you mean?